# finding similarities in a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to find the list of customers with similar groups.

Data:

```
customer    rating  lang
A           R       eng
B           R       rus
C           PG      rus
D           PG      eng
E           V       eng
F           V       rus
G           R       rus
H           PG      eng
I           V       eng
J           PG      eng
```

If I pass values of a new customer x with rating as 'PG' and lang as 'rus' it should return me the customers similar to x .

Input:

```
customer    rating  lang
x           PG      eng
```

Expected output :

```
[D, H, J]
```

how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to pass two parameters, `rating` and `lang`, and get the records in the DataFrame that have these parameters. You can do this with the following (thanks to jezrael).

```
def similar_customers(rating, lang):
    return df.loc[(df['rating'] == rating) & (df['lang'] == lang), 'customer'].tolist()
```

Using your example with a `rating` of 'PG' and a `lang` of 'eng':

```
similar_customers('PG', 'eng')

Out[3]: ['D', 'H', 'J']
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a dictionary to store all customer data, using **key:** tuple(rating,lang) and **value:** list of matching customers

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = [
    ("A",   "R",   "eng"),
    ("B",   "R",   "rus"),
    ("C",   "PG",  "rus"),
    ("D",   "PG",  "eng"),
    ("E",   "V",   "eng"),
    ("F",   "V",   "rus"),
    ("G",   "R",   "rus"),
    ("H",   "PG",  "eng"),
    ("I",   "V",   "eng"),
    ("J",   "PG",  "eng")
]
db = defaultdict(list)
for customer, rating, lang in data:
    db[rating,lang].append(customer)
```

finally you can check matching customer list as:

```
print(db["PG","eng"])
```

with output:

```
['D', 'H', 'J']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through customers comparing values. Assuming you have list of dictionaries (like `customers = [{"customer": "A", "rating": "R", "lang": "eng"}]`) possible solution is

```
similar = []
for customer in customers:
    if customer["rating"] == rating and customer["lang"] == lang:
        similar.append(customer["customer"])
print(similar)
```

Where `rating` and `lang` are parameters.

Comment: I have 6 variables including rating and lang  in my original data ..  and if atleast one of the attribute doesnt match in our database ..then my condition should satisfy as well

Comment: Then you can sum appropriate variables and check resulting sum